# How to use projection to select where x.val1=1, x.val2=2, etc.?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-4.1

How can use projection to select with where clause specification?

Perhaps something like?:

```
List<string> Titles = 
  iEnumerableResultSet.Select(x => x.Title = "Whatever", x=> x.Id =5).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, `Select` is poorly named. It is suppose to remind you of `SELECT` from SQL. That is, you specify the values that you want for each object in collection that you are `Select`ing over (if you know functional programming `Select` is the same as [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29)).

To filter, what you want is `Where`:

```
var filteredResultSet = 
    iEnumerableResultSet
       .Where(x => x.Title == "Whatever" && x.Id == 5)
       .ToList();
```

> How can use projection to select with where clause specification?

Now, your question seems to be asking how to both filter and project. You can say

```
var titles =
    iEnumerableResultSet
        .Where(x => x.Id == 5) // filter
        .Select(x => x.Title)  // project
        .ToList();
```

You can think of this as being like the SQL query

```
SELECT Title
FROM SomeTable
WHERE Id = 5
```

Answer (score 2):

'Select' isn't the extension method you want for filtering, you want to use 'Where' instead.  In this sense, the 'Select' is for selecting parts of the input objects to pass along ('projection' creation), not for deciding which objects do and don't get filtered out.

So, you want something like:

```
var title = enumerableResultSet.Where(x => x.Title == "Whatever" || x.Id == 5).ToList();
```